# Mockito: mock an indirectly injected singleton

Tags: kotlin, mockito, guice, apache-storm

I've got a storm bolt class that has quite a few field injected dependencies with guice, one of which, `MyMapper`, is a singleton:

```
class MyBolt(val injector: Injector): BaseRichBolt {
  ...
  @Inject
  @Transient
  private lateinit var myMapper: MyMapper

  override fun prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    super.prepare()
    // actually inject the fields
    this.injector.injectMembers(this)
  }

  override fun execute(input: Tuple) {
    // use myMapper here to query database
    val value: String = myMapper.read(someKey)
    ...
  }
}

@Singleton
class MyMapper @Inject constructor(private val myDAO: MyDAO) {
  ...
  fun read(key: String): String {
    // use myDAO to read from database
    return ...
  }
}
```

I'm writing a test for the bolt and would like to mock `myMapper` so that it does not actually need to go to database to read some `value`. In my test class, I've tried to mock it like the following:

```
class MyTest {
  private lateinit var injector: Injector
  private lateinit var myBolt: MyBolt

  private fun createInjector() : Injector {
    // create the injector with my guice modules
    ...
  }

  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    injector = createInjector()
    myBolt = Mockito.spy(MyBolt(injector))
  }

  @InjectMocks private val myMapper: MyMapper = mock(MyMapper::class.java)
  ...
  @Test
  fun test1() {
    ...
    Mockito.`when`(myMapper.read(any()).thenReturn("something")
    ...
    // execute on a test tuple and verify some method got called
    myBolt.execute(someTuple)
    verify(myBolt).someMethod(any())
  }
}
```

I'm hoping the above will redirect the call to `myMapper.read()` to return `something`. But it still tries to read from a database. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the actual initialization of the mocks either by using `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` as your runner, or by calling `Mockito.initMocks(this)`.

Something like either:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MyTest {
    // everything as it is right now
}
```

Or:

```
class MyTest {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        injector = createInjector()
        myBolt = Mockito.spy(MyBolt(injector))
        Mockito.initMocks(this)
    }

    // everything else
}
```

Comment: I tried both and neither worked in my case. It's still trying to read from the database.

Comment: Can you share what `createInjector` actually does? There's probably something there that's making `MyBolt::prepare` call to `Injector::injectMembers` actually get a real `MyMapper` instead of the mock

Comment: actually your solution might be working. However, I have no way to validate it because the `@InjectMocks` won't work with my case since `MyMapper` has a constructor injected dependency `MyDAO`.

Comment: You have at least two ways to go over that: 1. Mock the DAO as well, so it gets injected. 2. Extract an interface for `MyMpper`, and use that as the property in `MyBolt`. That way, your test is agnostic of the implementation details